# Can't install Windows on GPT drive

Tags: windows-8

I was trying to make a partition on my new ASUS x501A notebook as Windows 8 only has 1 drive. I used AOMEI Partition Assistant.

After restarting my system it was not able to load any OS. It only says *Loading System…* and then nothing.

When I tried to install Windows 8 again, it says that Windows can't be installed on GPT type drives. Before that I had formatted the C drive with Windows 8 on it.

Now my computer has no operating system and I can't install any on GPT drive. How can I convert it to NTFS – or any other way of installing Windows?

Comment: GPT and NTFS are completely different things. GPT is a partition layout standard, where MBR is the other option. NTFS is a file system. To install Windows on a GPT-initialised disk, you must install in UEFI mode (consult Google for more instructions there). Alternatively you can reinitialise the disk as MBR (possible data loss!) and install in legacy BIOS mode (not recommended!). Again, UEFI/GPT is recommended over BIOS/MBR where possible.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to alter the type of the *partition table* on the disk, not the filesystem type.

NTFS is a kind of filesystem, one of the many options available for abstracting the bytes present within your partitions into logical files within the directory tree. It is standard for Windows, but it doesn't care overmuch about the underlying partitions as long as they're present and it fits within them.

GPT is a method of delineating areas of your disk up into logical sections called partitions. It is a newer method than MBR, which used to be the standard, and does have some advantages - however, to install Windows to a GPT disk your system must be booted with EFI, which is a modern alternative to BIOS. According to the internet (at least, the four google pages I saw), your notebook does have UEFI.

It also apparently doesn't have an optical drive, which leads me to assume you're trying to install Windows using a USB stick. If not, **do so**, because you can boot them using EFI and you should then be able to install Windows on it. If you have a disk image of your Windows 8 DVD, I recommend using [this tool](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) to create an EFI-bootable Windows installation thumb drive.

If that's not possible, then you might try booting up a linux live image using [the tool here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) to get it onto a USB stick for booting, and then use parted to obliterate the GPT partition table and make a new MBR one, like so:

`parted /dev/sdX (where X is the letter of your hard drive, check dmesg to find out)`

`parted> mklabel msdos`

`parted> quit`

**This will *destroy* any data already on the disk. You will need to make new MBR partitions to hold Windows.**